# Translate jardesc content into jar-command

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am making some WebFilters for our WebLogic server and I've got everything up and running.

The problem is how I package the filters into jar-files. If I use the following jardesc-file and create the jar-file from Eclipse, everything is working fine and WebLogic has no problems loading the webfilter class. But as soon as I try to manually create the jar-file using just jar.exe I am hitting ClassNotFoundExceptions when loading the webcontainer in WebLogic.

**Working jardesc-file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252" standalone="no"?>
<jardesc>
    <jar path="C:/Workspace/Java/Jars/jars/corsfilter.jar"/>
    <options buildIfNeeded="true" compress="true" descriptionLocation="/CorsFilter/corsfilter.jardesc" exportErrors="false" exportWarnings="true" includeDirectoryEntries="false" overwrite="false" saveDescription="true" storeRefactorings="false" useSourceFolders="false"/>
    <storedRefactorings deprecationInfo="true" structuralOnly="false"/>
    <selectedProjects/>
    <manifest generateManifest="true" manifestLocation="" manifestVersion="1.0" reuseManifest="false" saveManifest="false" usesManifest="true">
        <sealing sealJar="false">
            <packagesToSeal/>
            <packagesToUnSeal/>
        </sealing>
    </manifest>
    <selectedElements exportClassFiles="true" exportJavaFiles="false" exportOutputFolder="false">
        <file path="/CorsFilter/.project"/>
        <file path="/CorsFilter/.classpath"/>
        <javaElement handleIdentifier="=CorsFilter/src"/>
    </selectedElements>
</jardesc>
```

**Current jar-command:**

```
jar -cvf corsfilter.jar .project .classpath -C .\bin dk\akait\filters\cors\CorsFilter.class
```

The jar-command creates a jar-file that seems to be equivalent to the one generated using the jardesc-file in Eclipse, except for what looks like some kind of symbolic link to the META-INF-folder in the root of the jar-file.

**Content of working jar-file:**
[image: Working jar-file]

**Content of non-working jar-file**
[image]

Can anyone explain what the right command for executing jar.exe is, given the jardesc-file?

Or

Can anyone explain what the META-INF file in the not working jar-file is?

*Updated with output of jar-command run using jdk-1.8.0_111*
[image: Output of jar-command]

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? I just tried your jar-command with jdk-1.8.0_92 64bit and did not get the ominous META-INF entry. However I'd really suggest to not rely on eclipse or any manually crafted command lines for packing you filters. You should give gradle a try. It may sound like an overkill, but it's actually pretty easy to get started as long as you don't want some very special stuff. If this is an option, I could craft some basic gradle file to do the packaging...

Comment: Could you perhaps add the command-line output of your jar-command as well?

Comment: Updated the question with java version and output from jar-command.

Comment: This is kind of strange. I tried to reproduce with the same Java version but did not get this empty META-INF entry. What tool are you using to inspect the generated jar files? And what about the gradle option?

Comment: I will try out gradle later today and yes, it does seem really strange about the META-INF entry. Might have to look into how zip-files are structured, to see if it is a red heering.

Comment: And btw I am using WinRar to inspect the Jar-file. I just find it strange that I get different results, when jardesc should be using jar.exe under the covers.

Comment: Tried WinRar with same Java version, still no empty META-INF file in the archive.

Comment: Have you tried to list the contents of the jar file using `jar tf corsfilter.jar`. I'm still not convinced this is a real issue. As a jar file is only a zip compressed file with a special structure, I would not be surprised, if eclipse implemented the jar creation based on the jardesc files differently...

Comment: The output of `jar tf corsfilter.jar` seems to be OK. I'll have to check out gradle later and try and retrace my steps, to see if I am making some mistake. Thanks for all your efforts @dpr

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments. I would think this is more like a problem with WinRar as with the actually created jar-file. Probably eclipse doesn't use the jar command internally to create jar-files based on the jardesc descriptions. And the jar-files differ somehow in their internal structure.

However I'd suggest not to rely on the eclipse output, if you want to create a jar-file that you are going to distribute somewhere. I personally like gradle a lot and it is pretty easy to use.

Simply create a `build.gradle` file in you project root directory with the following content:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

// this is only needed, if you want to include the single file only
// by default all compiled files will be added to the output jar
jar {
  include "dk/akait/filters/cors/CorsFilter.class"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '3.3'
}
```

Run

```
%PATH_TO_YOUR_GRADLE_BINARIES%/gradle wrapper
```

This will generate a local wrapper bat file that is used to ensure you are using the desired gradle version.

Run

```
%PROJECT_ROOT%/gradlew.bat build
```

and locate the jar-file under

```
%PROJECT_ROOT%/build/libs
```

You will however need to follow some conventions and place your java sources under a folder called `src/main/java` for this to work out-of-the-box. Or follow [this documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:working_with_java_source_sets) to setup different source folders.

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer I was looking for, but its my best bet so far and you put a considerable amount of time into helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your command line is even correct.
As according to `jar` output

> Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0PMe] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point]
>   [-C dir] files ...

And also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html

It is expect to be [manifest-file] and [entry-point] after [jar-file] name.

Try
`jar -cvf corsfilter.jar -C . .project .classpath -C .\bin dk\akait\filters\cors\CorsFilter.class`

Comment: `manifest-file` is optional and only needed, if the `m` (don't generate default manifest) switch is specified.

Comment: The result is exactly the same as the original command. Both manifest and entryfile are only used when their corresponding switches are used.